# Disable sudo -s and sudo -i

Tags: debian, sudo

I'd like to disable using sudo to become the root user so that every user will be forced to run privileged commands prefixed by sudo. This way, all these commands will be logged and a history is kept of access and modifications.

Any solution to achieve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. Do you also want them to not be able to run `sudo bash`? How about other shells? What if they use sudo to install a new shell, should that also be excluded? What if they use sudo to undo whatever limitation you impose?

Comment: What about `sudo bash` or `ln -s /bin/bash /tmp/ls; sudo /tmp/ls`?

Comment: @terdon sudo bash is fine because that command will be logged. After executing sudo -s the rest isn't logged anymore. If they undo the limitation, that is also logged.

Comment: @EarthMind `sudo bash` is basically the same as `sudo -s` (or `-i`): it will launch a new shell session, as root. If you're OK with `sudo bash`, you should be OK with `sudu -i`, both are logged in the same way.

Comment: @terdon In that case, I'm not okay with it :) in any case, the reason for this is not because users are not trusted in our environment. It's just to remove a bad habit

Comment: If they're not trusted, only give `sudo` access to a single menu command that you write, offering a restricted subset of commands and options. Better still don't offer `sudo` access at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Friendly reminder to get rid of bad `sudo` habits

So, if I understand correctly, you 'only' want a friendly reminder to get rid of bad habits. In other words, it is OK with a simple tool, that can easily be removed or worked around.

In that case a simple shellscript in a directory in PATH before the real `sudo` should work. I suggest that you

- give it the name `sudo`
- put it in the directory `/usr/local/bin`
- give it execute permissions

This means that when you or your colleagues type `sudo something` the system will find

```
/usr/local/bin/sudo  # the shellscript
```

before

```
/usr/bin/sudo        # the real sudo program
```

Shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 1 ] && (  [ "$1" == "-s" ] || [ "$1" == "-i" ] || [ "$1" == "bash" ] )
then
 echo "Please do not use 'sudo $1'"
 exit
else
 /usr/bin/sudo "$@"
fi
```

**Please tell me, if you want something that is more difficult to remove or work around**. In that case I have nothing to offer, and will delete this answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can list the commands a user can run in `sudoers`, and also exceptions.

The [`sudoers` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) even has an example of pretty much what you ask (adapted a bit here for Debian):

> ```
> Cmnd_Alias      SHELLS = /bin/sh, /bin/bash, /bin/bash, /usr/bin/zsh
> Cmnd_Alias      SU = /bin/su
>
> jill            SERVERS = /usr/bin/, !SU, !SHELLS
> ```
>
> For any machine in the `SERVERS` Host_Alias, jill may run any
> commands in the directory `/usr/bin/` except for those commands
> belonging to the `SU` and `SHELLS` Cmnd_Aliases.  While not
> specifically mentioned in the rule, the commands in the `PAGERS`
> Cmnd_Alias all reside in `/usr/bin` and have the noexec option set.

The same works with `ALL`:

```
someuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL, !SU, !SHELLS
```

Trying gets you this:

```
$ sudo -s
Sorry, user someuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on thishost.
$ sudo bash -c "echo please"
Sorry, user someuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -c echo please' as root on thishost.
```

And `sudo -l` shows you can't run those particular commands.

Note that you need to explicitly list all the shells if the default is that they can run anything. E.g. `su` also runs a shell, so if it was allowed, they could use `sudo su` (as useless as that is in general). And because I made a typo above, `/bin/dash` would still be available.

---

In any case, listing exceptions like this is never going to work as an actual restriction. There's nothing stopping the user from making a copy of some shell with another name (`sudo cp -a /bin/bash /bin/cash`), or even just running `sudo vi` and hitting `:shell`. Sure, you could probably configure editors and such to prevent shelling out, but you'd need to find and plug all the holes and probably still wouldn't be able to stop the leaks. Even so, apparently some people think this is a good idea, as I've had the pain of using such a system before.

Apart from logging, I assume the reason to do something like this is to reduce accidents, by not having people keep a privileged shell open to run every command. But having to prepend `sudo` to the command doesn't really make the command less likely to have typos. You can still `sudo rm -rf *` in the wrong directory, or mistake `/dev/sdd` for `/dev/sdf`, etc.

Denying a privileged shell also has a practical problem for the admin. If the system has directories that are not accessible to the admin's regular account, they're going to want to run a privileged shell to be able to get in there, to see the file listing, and to tab-complete filenames. Without a shell, they'd need to always do `sudo ls path/to/dir` (not just `sudo ls`, since they can't get there), and then copypaste the filenames manually when doing something with them. That's highly annoying, but will at least reduce mistakes per time unit by making everything slower to do.

Comment: I know this is old but I have found workaround for this "blockade"  
simply call `sudo sudo su` or `sudo sudo bash` and you are root

Comment: @Iluvatar, oh indeed. Would need to add `sudo` itself to the banlist. Like I said, I just copied that off the man page, funny that they've forgotten about `sudo` itself there...

Comment: would also point out that any intermediate command like `stdbuf` works around this, like `sudo stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 bash`, `sudo unbuffer bash` also somewhat works but would require tweaks

Comment: @Iluvatar, yes, that's what the answer says too, in that first paragraph under the divider line.

Answer (score 1):

### WARNING : sudo sudo su

Just have one problem, if a sudoers user make a

```
sudo sudo su
```

He can access to root shel !

So, it's necessary to had /usr/bin/sudo in Cmnd_Alias.

```
Cmnd_Alias      SHELLS = /bin/sh, /bin/bash, /bin/bash, /usr/bin/zsh
Cmnd_Alias      SU = /bin/su,/usr/bin/sudo
```

or in script

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ] && (  [ "$1" == "-s" ] || [ "$1" == "sudo" ] || [ "$1" == "-i" ] || [ "$1" == "bash" ] )
then
 echo "Please do not use 'sudo $1'"
 exit
else
 /usr/bin/sudo "$@"
fi`
```