# Command history for multiple users from sudo/wheel group

Tags: bash, sudo, command-history

I working in an environment with multiple users who can invoke `sudo` with their own passwords.
Most users login via `ssh`, call `sudo -i` and do "work".
The problem is when it comes to identify WHO did something that broke working service/script.

Is there a way to preserve separate cmd history? Right now I have to `su root` and call `history` which:

1. wont show me all called commands - because multiple root sessions will overwrite bash history.
2. I dont know who called which command as root

I know that each user could skip `sudo -i` and call each command `sudo <cmd>` and that would be saved in each users bash history, but I wont be able to "force" that with words(only with configuration)

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596722/disable-sudo-s-and-sudo-i

Comment: Do you have multiple users who effectively have **full** root capabilities? It is possible to restrict different users to have access to different subsets of root capabilities.

Comment: @JeremyBoden I have multiple users with admin privileges(I am one of them). The fact that every admin have full access is not a problem(due to the way we work) but I would like to make sure that we can pretty much blame single person if something goes wrong or if someone's account is breached it would be easier to identify who was "hacked".

Comment: "_if someone's account is breached it would be easier to identify who was "hacked"_" not at all. If the root account is breached then you can't trust any log file written and stored locally

Comment: "Pride comes before a fall".

Answer (score 0):

`visudo`

Include a line:-

`Defaults logfile=/var/log/sudo` (or similar)

Note:- You need to be root to read the log. Example:-

```
Jun 17 20:56:26 : jeremy : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jeremy ; USER=root ;
    COMMAND=/usr/bin/ls -lh
```

Comment: Any user with full sudo access can presumably adjust this log.

Comment: If I do `sudo -i` (I have pointed that this is most common case), it wont show any later command in log

Comment: `sudo -i` is equivalent to `sudo /bin/bash` - you might as well give everyone a card with the root password printed in very large characters.